# How to declare a table's name within a variable using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

### The goal

Declare a *"global"* variable that houses the name of a table within a **stored procedure's** scope.

### The scenario

I'm designing a simple **stored procedure** with an `IF` statement inside and I need to use the name of a table in many places of the code.

### The problem

I really don't know how to do (*a.k.a. "I don't know the syntax"*).

### What I already did

In a few tests, I've tried the following code:

```
[...]

BEGIN
DECLARE TableName = "Users";

    [...]

    INSERT INTO TableName ([...]) VALUES ([...]);

    [...]
END
```

But I received a **(1064) SQL Syntax Error** around the `INSERT INTO [...]` line.

So, someone can help me with this problem?

Comment: You need to use [13.5. SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
1,DECLARE var_name [, var_name] ... type [DEFAULT value]

[...]

BEGIN
modify //DECLARE TableName = "Users";
DECLARE TableName CHAR(20) DEFAULT 'Users';

    [...]

    INSERT INTO TableName ([...]) VALUES ([...]);

    [...]
END
```

2,More about declaring variables refer mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-local-variable.html

Comment: An *1146 error* occurs: `The table '` **`app.TableName`** `' doesn't exist.`

Comment: Yes, `app.TableName`.

Comment: I do not understand app.TableName what is